I exchanged scam tokens,pls help me
I exchanged ETH for scam coins through BYBITWEB3 on UNISWAP, now they cannot be sold on BYBITWEB3 DEFI (he writes that the contract has closed source code) and when trying to reverse exchange through ETH
on UNISWAP, [![enter image description here][1]][1]it is impossible to go further than 1 point, although I confirm...Pls ,help me..

Please, give more information about your problem. Whats is the link of BYBITWEB3? What is the token address? Be aware that your wallet address probably will be revealed if you share the token address.
